# Run Meteor on Raspberry PI as a Client or Service for IOT

Tags: meteor, raspberry-pi

I have a Cordova/Meteor App for Mobile that is Publishing Data to the Cloud, I was able to install Meteor on the RPI and get it running, now I am trying to figure out how to run the app as a client waiting for changes to the Data to push to push and or Pull from IOT devices.

Do I figure out how to get meteor to run as a service and constantly run a browser to keep it activity connected.

Can I setup a subscribe on the Server-side, to keep it listening for changes.

Any ideas on directions would be appreciated.

Comment: Could possible look at creating an API service with it. Check out restivus in the atmosphere website. Might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Checkout DDPconnect. You may connect your subscriptions from the Pi to the Cloud and get the messages when clients posting new data.

Comment: I was able to set it to set it to startup meteor with a script, it seems it doesn't need a connected client to continue running, I came from an IIS background so I thought that it need one.

I am using a ddp connection to keep the data in sync with the server and the app is connected to the same server, i am getting near real-time updates.

One trick I learned was to update a value in a collection that the RPI is connected to to keep the socket running, as it dies after +12hrs so I update once every 6 hrs using a cron job on the server.